# How to execute a batch script during build?

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013, direct3d

I have a directory structure in my project that is as follows:

```
core/
  media/
  shaders/
  src/
  inc/

apps/
  app1/
    src/
    inc/
    shaders/
    media/
    bin/
  app2/
    ...
```

When building a project inside one of the "app" folders, I would like to take all the files in core/shaders and core/media and copy them to the corresponding app/shaders and app/media.  This seems like it could be implemented in a batch script.  However, I am unsure how to invoke one during the build.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio right click on Start up project. Select Properties -> Build Events ..put in your copy batch command into Post-Build event command line text box.